# How to extract data from the HTML of the website through PhantomJS Driver

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless

i am trying to parse the following webpage https://shop.sprouts.com/shop/flyer using .Net, Selenium, PhantomJs. The data that I am seeing in the element's text is completely different than what I see on the screen. Is there a better way to parse the webpage?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
[TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    const string PhantomDirectory = @"..\..\..\packages\PhantomJS.2.1.1\tools\phantomjs";

[TestMethod]
    public void GetSproutsWeeklyAdDetails()
    {
      using (IWebDriver phantomDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(PhantomDirectory))
      {
        phantomDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://shop.sprouts.com/shop/flyer");
        var elements = phantomDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("cell-title-text"));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use chromedriver instead. It has already supported headless mode.

Comment: Thank you @baudan for your input. i will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *WebSite* `https://shop.sprouts.com/shop/flyer` to parse the data that you are seeing in the element's text you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of all the desired elements* and you can use the following solution:

- Solution:

  ```
  IList<IWebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//span[@class='cell-title-text' and @ng-bind-html='productTitle()']")));
  foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  }
  ```
- Equivalent Python Exmaple:

  ```
  driver.get('https://shop.sprouts.com/shop/flyer')
  myList = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='cell-title-text' and @ng-bind-html='productTitle()']")))
  for item in myList:
      print(item.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Sweet Corn, 1 EA
  Cantaloupe Melons, 1 LB
  Red Cherries
  Half Chicken Breast
  Roma Tomatoes
  100% Grass Fed Ground Beef Value Pack
  Colby Jack Rbst Free
  Walnut Halves & Pieces
  ```