# Button is not clickable on webpage

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318120/how-to-extract-data-from-the-html-of-the-website-through-phantomjs-driver) some time back and I am still facing random errors trying to parse a webpage. 
The scenario is that the system goes to https://www.sprouts.com/store/tx/plano/plano/ clicks on "VIEW THIS STORE’S SPECIALS" navigates to https://shop.sprouts.com/shop/flyer and extracts the stores specials. Currently the code below works 10% or 20% of the times only as it is unable to find the button to click and navigate to the next page. 
What am i doing wrong?

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

      [TestClass]
      public class UnitTest1
      {
        ChromeDriver driver;
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait;
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Startup()
        {
          var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
          //chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
          chromeOptions.AddArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
          chromeOptions.AddArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
          //chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
          //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
          chromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");

          var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
          ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path);
          driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
          webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
          driver.Quit();
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetSproutsWeeklyAdDetails()
        {   
          try
          {        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.sprouts.com/store/tx/plano/plano/");
          }
          catch (TimeoutException timeoutException)
          {
            driver.Navigate().Refresh();
          }
          webDriverWait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
          **var elements1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
            By.XPath("//div[@class='cell small-6 divider']/button")));
          elements1.First().Click();**
    <= the system is unable to find the button 80% of the times

          webDriverWait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
          var elements2 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
            By.XPath("//li[@class='cell-wrapper' and @ng-repeat='item in items track by $index']"))); 
//More code below    
          }
        }
      }
```

**source code of area where button that is not clickable:**

```
<div class="cell small-6 divider">        
        <button onclick="viewStoreFlyer(event, 101)">
          <img src="https://www.sprouts.com/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress/dist/assets/images/weekly-specials-stores-icon.svg" width="32" alt="" role="presentation">
          <br>
          View this store’s specials
        </button>        
      </div>
```

Comment: In your previous question you wanted to parse the element's text so we have used `visibility_of_all_elements_located`. But in this question your requirement is to click on `VIEW THIS STORE’S SPECIALS`, so your requirement have changed ans so the solution will also change. Perhaps @AndreiSuvorkov answer points you to the right direction. let us know if you need further help.

Comment: Hello @DebanjanB, the solution suggested below does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my perpesctive the code is almost good, except two things. You are waiting for all elements to be visible and then immediately want to click on the first of them. Firstly on the website is only one element with following xPath, so there is no need to locate a list. The second is - when element is visible, it does not means it is clickable, so the better way to deal with this would be:

```
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='cell small-6 divider']/button")));
```

***PS:*** the answer @DebanjanB has provided is very good in that case, since you just wanted to extract the text withoun interacting with element. In our case we have to wait until elelment will be ready to recieve a click, that's why `ElementToBeClickable` is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding a thread sleep just before the button was clicked.

```
var elements1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(
        By.XPath("//div[@class='cell small-6 divider']/button")));
Thread.Sleep(2000);
elements1.Click();
```